# Blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ at a point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let  $x:= (0,0) \in \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. What is the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ at $x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't really have a special name, but the thing to notice is that blowing up takes the two lines through $x$ (one from each ruling) and separates them, so that the proper transforms $L_1$ and $L_2$ of these lines are $(-1)$-curves, and there is a third $(-1)$-curve linking them, namely the exceptional divisor $E$ (this follows from the general fact that blowing up a point on a curve in a surface decreases its self-intersection by $1$).

Now, Castelnuovo's contractibility criterion tells us that we can blow down any $(-1)$-curve to a smooth point. If we blow down $E$ we get back where we started, but if we blow down (without loss of generality) $L_2$, the proper transform of $E$ under the blowing down now has self intersection $0$. Meanwhile, the self-intersection of $L_1$ doesn't change so it is now the unique $(-1)$-curve. From here, it's not so hard to show that you have obtained the Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb F_1$, also known as the blow-up of $\mathbb P^2$ at a point.

Now you may know that $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ is also known as $\mathbb F_0$, and the blow up/blow down procedure described above will (with a bit more care since $\mathbb F_{>0}$ are not totally homogeneous) in general transform $\mathbb F_e$ into $\mathbb F_{e+1}$. So while the blowup of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ at a point doesn't have a special name, it's the first in an infinite sequence of surfaces that form "roofs" relating all of the Hirzebruch surfaces (roof just refers to the shape of the relevant diagram).

**Edited to add:** some user has been trying to edit this answer today due to a misunderstanding. Please read more carefully; I do not claim that the blowup of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ is $\mathbb F_1$, but rather that one obtains the latter after also blowing down the proper transform of a line through the center of the initial blowup.

Comment: Could you explain what a $(-1)$-curve is?

Comment: Yes: a curve $C \subset S$ is a **$\bf (-1)$-curve** if $C \cong \mathbb P^1$ and $C^2 = -1$ (where negative self-intersection can be understood as the degree of the normal bundle $N_{C/S}$, which here is isomorphic to $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-1)$). As alluded to in the answer, it's a theorem of Castelnuovo that a curve on a surface can be blown down to a smooth point if and only if it is a $(-1)$-curve.

Comment: Thanks. You say in your answer that in some sense the blow-up separates the lines through $x$. Is there an explicit map for that?

Comment: In an affine chart $U$ where $x=y=0$ cuts out the origin and $xy=0$ cuts out the two lines, we blow up with coordinates $x = u$ and $y = uv$ (call this the first blowup chart; this is one of two charts needed to cover $\pi^{-1}(U)$), so $xy = u^2v = 0$. This gives us $u^2=0$ cutting out the exceptional divisor with multiplicity $2$, and $v=0$ cutting out the proper transform of $y=0$ (why not $x=0$? Because $v=y/u=y/x=0$ when $y=0$.). In the second blowup chart (still over the same chart $U$ on the base $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$), let $x = st$ and $y = t$ so $xy=st^2=0$....

Comment: ....so we have $t^2=0$ as the equation of the exceptional divisor hence $s=0$ cuts out the proper transform of $x=0$ (since $s=x/t=x/y=0$ when $x=0$). The reason only one of the (proper transforms of the) lines through $x$ shows up in each blowup chart is because their slopes are $0$ and $\infty$, the two points that are deleted to produce the standard open affines on $\mathbb P^1$ (the copy introduced by blowing up, not the two copies forming the base variety).

Comment: @TabesBridges Is the blow up of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ also the same as $\mathbb{P}^2$ blown up at two points, with the -1 curve over the point on $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ corresponding to the proper transform of the line through the two points on $\mathbb{P}^2$?

Comment: Yes. Let $E_1, E_2$ denote the two exceptional curves from blowing up $\mathbb P^2$, with $L$ the proper transform of the line connecting the centers of the blowup. All three are $(-1)$-curves, and after blowing down $L$ the self-intersections of the proper transforms of $E_1, E_2$ increase by $1$ to $0$. As such, $|E_1|$ and $|E_2|$ are basepoint-free linear systems (in fact pencils) which give a map to $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ that you should be able to check is an isomorphism.